# How to find out the cardinality of $\mathcal{S}_\beta(S_8)=\{\alpha\in S_8: \alpha\beta\alpha=\beta, |\beta|=2\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am stuck in the following problem. Please help me.

Let us consider the symmetric group $S_n$  of order $n!$. Say $n=8$ viz we are talking about $S_8$.

Now let $\alpha, \beta$ be two permutation in $S_8$ satisfying $\alpha\beta\alpha=\beta$ where $|\beta|=2$ is given. How many $\alpha$ are possible ?

In other words we need to find the cardinality of $\mathcal{S}_\beta(S_n)$ for some fixed $\beta$ where  $\mathcal{S}_\beta(S_8):=\{\alpha\in S_8: \alpha\beta\alpha=\beta, |\beta|=2\}$.

I am confused because I know disjoint cycles commute but will it be helpful to crack this one? I don't think so. Moreover, I tried to use conjugation but in vain. How to find this cardinality no idea

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question as posed makes no sense.  Do you mean $S_\beta(S_8)=\lbrace \alpha \in S_8 : \alpha\beta\alpha=\beta\rbrace$ for some fixed $\beta$ satisfying $|\beta|=2$ ?  And does $|\beta|$ mean the order of $\beta$? Or....?

Comment: Ok let me make it clear for you. here $\beta$ is a fixed permutation in $S_8$ of order 2. And we are to collect all those $\alpha\in S_8$ such that they satisfy $\alpha\beta\alpha=\beta$. Moreover, yes sir, you are right, $|\beta|$ is used to denote the order of $\beta$.

Comment: Anything else is required to make it clear, please let me know, Or you can edit the question also if you find in appropriate

Comment: Yes, this makes sense now.  You want the information that $|\beta|=2$ to appear outside the definition of $S_\beta(S_8)$, not inside.

Comment: yap ! thats what I wanted. Sorry for my mistake that troubled you :-(

Comment: I would first transform the equation to $\beta^{-1}\alpha\beta=\alpha^{-1}$. Then start looking for the kind of cycle patterns (for $\alpha$) that can be inverted by a product of disjoint 2-cycles. All the cycles can (think: dihedral group), but the number of disjoint 2-cycles has less options. This, unfortunately, leads to a case-by-case analysis (read: a lot of work). I don't see anything nice right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will help you a little through it. Here is a way to use conjugation. If we conjugate $\beta$ to $\beta'$ We will have that :

$$|S_{\beta}(S_n)|=|S_{\beta'}(S_n)| $$

Now I claim that any $\beta$ of order $2$ is a product of disjoint transpositions and that (in $S_8$), up to conjugation we get only four different cases :

$$\beta_1=(1,2)\text{, } \beta_2=(1,2)(3,4)\text{, } \beta_3=(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)\text{ and } \beta_4=(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8) $$

Hence, to answer your question, it suffices to answer it for each $\beta$ above. Now you could use a computer to get the number you want for each (or you could do it "by hand" but it could become nasty...).

Comment: Yes, I tried in hand and indeed, the outcome was really a disaster :-D but anyway, thanks for your help